# Keypress event to an unfocused window - Win32api

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation, bots, win32gui

I want to write a script that simulates a key press and release so that the input goes to a specific window, even if it's not the focused one and in background or minimized. I was wondering if that's possible.
The script I made does it every 2 seconds when the focused window (where the inputs go) is the one I decided, otherwise nothing happens, then it loops again. But it's not what I was aiming for.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import win32api, win32gui, win32con
import time

def press():
    win32api.keybd_event(0x08, 0,0,0) # 0x08 is the hex for the return key
    time.sleep(.1)
    win32api.keybd_event(0x08,0 ,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP ,0)

def __get_window():
    CurrentWindow = win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
    return CurrentWindow

if __name__ == "__main__":      

    while True:

        if __get_window() == "PROCESS_NAME": # Name of the process
            press()

        time.sleep(2)
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 this solution is for c++ but i think method's name should be same as defined in 
 win32api python 

 consider hwnd as window handle
 and Vk_A as value of key which you want to remotely pressed and released
 you need to use "SendMessage" or "PostMessage" method

 if you know window handle you can use 
   SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETFOCUS, 0, 0) 
 or
   SendMessage(hwnd, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_ACTIVE, 0)

 then you need to use following methods together
   SendMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, Vk_A, 0)
   SendMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, Vk_A, 0)
```